# How do I diagnose a failure in the Membership service on an ASP.NET remote site?

Tags: asp.net

Yesterday I added a custom MembershipProvider to an ASP.NET web application, but when I deployed the application to its remote host server, it failed.  I know I had the login info correct, and I also know that for nearly any exception in the login process, the Login control displays the standard error message, "Your login failed", so I assume something is wrong in the code/config.

What can I do to diagnose what is wrong on the server?

BTW:  This weekend I only have FTP access to the server, so no event log, and CustomErrors is already set to Off.

**THE END:**  I was an idiot, and using the wrong query window to check if the my login actually existed on the server.

Comment: @Darin, I only have FTP access to the server.

Comment: What is the error its giving then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try a couple of things:

- Set custom errors to off in the
  webconfig and look at what error its
  giving
- Look at the event log to see
  if there is an useful info for this
  app

If the above are not fruitful, then go for remote debugging!